# Using Queue in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, queue, console-application

Ok, so I am working on a console application that pulls from an API every 3 seconds. The API returns a list of "Messages" that I would need to add to a queue and have something in the background constantly checking for new items in the queue, looping through the items, the doing something with the items.

**Here is what I have so far:**
Main Program Method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo answer = Console.ReadKey(true);
    if (answer.Key == ConsoleKey.Y)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            foreach (MessageObject message in messageQueue)
            {
                SendCommand(message.Message);

                // Debug
                Console.WriteLine(message.Message);
                messageQueue.Dequeue();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

CheckChat Method

```
static private async void CheckChat()
{
    Chat chat = await ChatAPI.GetChat(428);

    foreach (MessageObject chatMessage in chat.Messages)
    {
        messageQueue.Enqueue(chatMessage);
    }
}
```

However, i get the following error:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll`

`Additional information: Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated.`

I understand that I am adding items to the list while looping through the queue, but how would I continuously check items in queue in the background as im adding objects?

Comment: this means, you cannot enqueue during enumeration

Comment: @Legends Correct, but if im always (every x seconds) needing to add items to my Queue form the API, how would I do this?

Comment: Most likely your async is changing the contents of messageQueue while you are busy.  Why don't you try and just check for size (length) and then read one at a time.  .... or as Ben mentioned - create a copy and read from that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a copy of the Queue if you want to enumerate it while it's being modified, for example you can:

```
foreach (MessageObject message in messageQueue.ToList())
```

Note that in all likelyhood your queue should also be a [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) since you're doing operations across threads.

Comment: As a tip - I'd consider using ReactiveExtensions if I were you, it's a lot more elegant than a `while(true)` loop, performs better since it's not a busy wait and conveys intent better. It's definitely worth learning in my opinion for this sort of thing.

Comment: I am still running into an error here: http://prntscr.com/6slvyi and I will definitely consider it, thanks!

Comment: @EliteGamer are you using a `ConcurrentQueue`? Regular Queues will most definitely fail here because of cross-thread access since they're not [a thread safe collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). (That is, the collection is being modified _while_ the `ToList()` is executing.

Comment: just as comment for answer - no point of `Select(x => x)` operation as `ToList()` always creates a new list.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov you're probably right, I'm just overly defensive after seeing a `.ToList` implementation on a custom object that checked if the argument is already a list and only performed a cast instead of copying but  I have no reason to assume that's the case in OP's code.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thank you. Its been a long day already and I will be sure to use the ConcurrentQueue instead of what I have now.

Comment: @EliteGamer when in doubt - always prefer thread safe collections and taking locks to not doing so. This is just the sort of pain Rx would save you by the way - happy coding and good luck :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I am now using a concurrent queue, but my while loop is eating up CPU, how would i make this perform better? Or should this be asked as another question?

Comment: @EliteGamer I'll say what I said 2 times before - ReactiveExtensions :) If you really _can't_ use it, add a `Thread.Sleep(200)` at the end of that `while(true)` loop to give it a chance to block - but you're solving problems you shouldn't care about right now, just so you know.

Answer (score 0):

You could use (for instance) the `while` loop instead of `foreach`:

```
while (messageQueue.Count != 0)
{
    MessageObject message = messageQueue.Dequeue();
    Console.WriteLine(message.Message);
}
```

In this case there is no problem with modification of a queue.